# Transformar endereço de memoria em String é possivel ? Golang

Tags: golang

```html
func listContainer(client *azblob.Client) error {
    list := client.NewListContainersPager(&azblob.ListContainersOptions{})

    for list.More() {
        resp, _ := list.NextPage(context.TODO())

        for _, _container := range resp.ContainerItems {
            fmt.Printf("%v", _container, &_container)

        }
    }

    return nil

}
```

esse codigo acima me da esse retorno:

```
&{0xc00008a210 0xc0000a8000 <nil> map[] <nil>}
```

Tem como transformar isso em uma string ?

Comment: O `container` parece ter maps e slices e ponteiros internamente. Para converter para "string", de forma a manter todos os dados, deve codificar para algum formato (json, flatbuffers...) ou deve fazer um loop e exibir cada um dos itens.

Answer (score -1):

consegui resolver, usando ponteiro.
Ficando assim:

```
func listBlob(client *azblob.Client, containerName string) error {
pager := client.NewListBlobsFlatPager(containerName, &azblob.ListBlobsFlatOptions{})

for pager.More() {
    resp, _ := pager.NextPage(context.TODO())

    for _, blob := range resp.Segment.BlobItems {
        fmt.Printf("%v \n", *blob.Name)

    }
}
return nil
```

}

usei um ponteiro:

```
fmt.Printf("%v \n", *blob.Name)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).